# Dimension retained in spanning subset

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying for a Linear Algebra exam and found this question that I can't find an answer to.

Let $V$ be a 5-dimensional vector space, and let $X$ be a subset of $V$ which spans $V$. What can be said about $X$?

$a)$ Must be linearly independent

$b)$ Must consist of of at least 5 elements

$c)$ Must have exactly 5 elements

$d)$ Must have at most 5 elements

$e)$ Must be a basis for V

$f)$ Must be linearly dependent

Nothing is said about linear dependence, so I'm comfortable eliminating $a$, $e$, and $f$. After that, I'm not quite sure.

I know that a basis for $V$ contains 5 elements, but I don't know what else can be inferred from the information.

Comment: Just because nothing is said about linear independence, doesn't mean you should feel comfortable to eliminate it. If you truly want to justify that a) need not hold, you'll have to produce a counterexample: a spanning set that fails to satisfy a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be clear if you remember that the (finite) dimension $d$ of a vector space is also characterised by:

(a) $d$ is the minimal number of elements of a spanning subset;

(b) $d$ is the maximal number of elements  of a linearly independent subset.

Comment: So does that tell me that it must contain at least 5 elements since it never says that it is linearly independent?

Comment: It tells you exactly that.